# android RadioButton not selecting the right buttonTint when created programmatically why

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to create new RadioButton programmatically to be the same as below :

```
         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_ok_radio_button"
            android:buttonTint="@drawable/ok_radio_button_text_color"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textColor="@drawable/ok_radio_button_text_color" />
```

i do the following in code:

```
            val rb = AppCompatRadioButton(this)
            rb.id = R.id.ok_id
            rb.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_ok_radio_button)
            rb.supportButtonTintList =
                ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.ok_radio_button_text_color))
           rb.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.ok_radio_button_text_color)))
```

below the 2 xml files drawable used:

`bg_radio_button.xml` which exist in Drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_ok_radio_button_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_checked="false" />

 </selector>
```

`ok_radio_button_text_color.xml` which exist in color folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item  android:color="@color/stateGreen"/>
 </selector>
```

the problem is the xml way works differently than the Kotlin way, when i work with kotlin way and click the radio button it is colored all green with text color and tint color also green but when i use the XML way the color of tint and text is white when select the radioButton any help?
ME i need to use the KOTLIN way not xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,  ColorStateList was misread. It created from color

```
ColorStateList.valueOf(**getColor**(R.color.ok_radio_button_text_color))
```

Default color is @color/stateGreen
so background and text is colored as green

Fix: fix must read colorStatList value from xml file res/color/ok_radio_button_text_color

```
    val colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.ok_radio_button_text_color)
    rb.supportButtonTintList = colorStateList
    rb.setTextColor(colorStateList)
```